# How do I run a .java file on a server that other java programs can interact with?

Tags: java, web-services, networking

Can someone please outline the general process of how I would place a .java file on a server and have it run continuously on a certain port? I created a program that listens on a specified port for connections, and then opens streams between two client applications. I can run it fine using localhost, but have no idea how I would run it using a server. I have a FreeNAS server setup in my house, and have seen tutorials on how to install Tomcat on it, but none of them explain what to actually do with the java file. Do I just place it in a certain directory? How do the client programs know where to look for the file?

Comment: Is the program you created a simple socket application or is it utilizing the Java WS API?

Comment: Socket program @GeorgeLaed

Comment: In my opinion, you need a service oriented approach, try following this tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayk.html

Answer (score 0):

You build up a JAR file that is constantly running on the server that contains your implementation of the socket program. What you could do is have a properties file that is shipped by the JAR file that has a default port. In case you want to override this port you could.

Other clients can connect to that server that contains the running JAR. You could make use of Linux. Clients would connect to the server name at the specified port. For example, your JAR file is running on database.example.com at port 2370 then your client would connect to this server and port.

I hope that helps.